# SelectedValue property for a Autocomplete User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

First off, forgive my English, my attempt, I am creating a autocomplete user control, to replace drop downs, I have created the user control, and its working fine. Now for simplicity sake, I need to provide a public property in my User Control to get the selected id, similar to the SelectedValue of the DropDrown control.  I'm stuck with this, any ideas will be appreciated.

---

> Hi **My Code**
>
> **UserControl.ascx**
>
> <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Code
>   File="UserControl.ascx.cs"
>       Inherits="UserControl" %> <%@ Register
>   Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
>   TagPrefix="cc1" %>
>
> function DispValue(sender, e) {
>           alert(e.get_value() + "   : user control");
>           document.getElementById(hiddenFieldName.Client ID).value =
>   e.get_value();
>       }
>
> **UserControl.ascx.cs**
>
> public partial class UserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
>       protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           ACEName.ContextKey = "1";
>       }
>
> ```
> public String SelectedValue
> {
>     get { return this.hdnValue.Value; }
> }
>
> public String SelectedText
> {
>     get { return this.Name.Text; }
> } }
> ```
>
> **MyAspxPage.aspx**
>
> <%@ Register Src="~/UserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="puc"
>   TagName="UserControl" %> 
>         
>       
>       
>       
>       
>           
>               
>                   
>                       Patient Name
>
> **MyAspxPage.cs**  DataTable dt;
>       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           if (!IsPostBack)
>           {
>               dt = new DataTable();
>               dt.Columns.Add("col1");
>               dt.Columns.Add("col2");
>               dt.Columns.Add("col3");
>               dt.Columns.Add("col4");
>               dt.Columns.Add("col5");
>               dt.Columns.Add("col6");
>
> ```
>         if (Session["dt"] == null)
>         {
>             dt = AddRow(dt);
>             gvPatient.DataSource = dt;
>             gvPatient.DataBind();
>             Session["dt"] = dt;
>             //ViewState["dt"] = dt;
>         }
>         else
>             dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];//ViewState["dt"];
>
>     }
> }
>
> private DataTable AddRow(DataTable dt)
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
>     {
>         DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
>         dr[0] = "";
>         dr[1] = "";
>         dr[2] = "";
>         dr[3] = "";
>         dr[4] = "";
>         dr[5] = "";
>         dt.Rows.Add(dr);
>     }
>     return dt;
> }
> ```
>
> protected void GridPatient_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           foreach (GridViewRow item in gvPatient.Rows)
>           {
>               UserControl ptuc =
>   (UserControl)item.FindControl("pucPatient1");
>               string id = ptuc.SelectedValue;
>            }
>       }
>
> public void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           foreach (GridViewRow item in gvPatient.Rows)
>           {
>               if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
>               {
>                   UserControl ptuc =
>   (UserControl)item.FindControl("pucPatient1");
>                   string id = ptuc.SelectedValue;//getting null value.
>                   string patientName = ptuc.SelectedText;
>                }
>           }    }
>
> this is all what i did.
>
> Thanking You, cheers Sharanamma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using the `TextBox` control in background for your `Autocomplete`. So, define the `SelectedValue` as following:

```
public string SelectedValue
{
   get { return this.textBox.Text; }
}
```

Or if you need the ID of the selected value, not display text, then place `HiddenField` near your `TextBox` and populate the ID of selected value from autocomlete using JavaScript. And the use it on the server side:

```
public string SelectedValue
{
   get { return this.hiddenField.Text; }
}
```

Comment: i had one more problem i,e if i expose OnClientItemSelected in autoCompleteextender in usercontrol event as a property means I'm not getting set property of SelectedValue because previously i set hidden field value in onClientItemSelect event of autocompleteextender which is in UserControl and exposed this value in SelectedValue property, so how can i set this property?. any solution means ll be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use findcontrol() in gridview's RowDataBound Event.
May be it can helps you to find values of hidden field